# Make all points on a plane turn towards a specific mesh in animation

Tags: animation, mesh, geometry-nodes, instances

I have seen several videos (like [this one](https://youtube.com/watch?v=CedtNe4CFrk&t=87s)) where the points are made to all point towards a mesh, but none are using animation.

My goal is to have a lot of randomly rotated points on a plane (I have already done this) that then turn towards a certain point, so that you can see them rotating on the z axis towards it. This is being done in Blender 3.2.2.

The problem is how to get the randomly rotated points to be shown moving towards a specific mesh in the animation so that it is smooth.

Comment: hello could you please show one of these videos in order to understand what you mean?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CedtNe4CFrk&t=87s

Comment: What's the actual question and problem?

Comment: the problem is how to get the randomly rotated points to be shown moving towards a specific mesh in the animation so that it is smooth

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the clarification. I've added the missing pieces to your question and made a little example how to solve this. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a smooth animation just mix the rotation values with a *Mix* node. This way you can seamlessly switch between the "random pose" and the "point-to pose".

**Example:**

[image: example animation]

*"Random Pose" - instance objects have a random rotation*:
[image: random pose]

*"Point-To Pose" - instance objects are rotated to point at the Empty object*:
[image: point to pose]

*Now, for the animation add a *Mix* node and add keyframes for the *Factor* value. (0 = random rotation, 1 = point-to rotation)*
[image: mixing the poses]

That's it! Of course, you can use another mesh object instead of the Empty ;-)